# 24hr password array giving syntax errors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, browser

I made a script that (should) change the password daily using an array of passwords for each day, but I keep getting all sorts of errors.

```html
<script>
</script>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="text1" /><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="text2" /><br>
  <input type="button" class="button4" style="background-color:#9c9c9c" value="Login" onclick="javascript:validate()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  type = "text/javascript"
  window.onload = function() {
    chgDailyImg();
  }

  function chgDailyImg() {
    var imagearray = new Array();
    imagearray[0] = "9G7DcwnWafg*EtMH";
    imagearray[1] = "MDe^5qHTG#P9dHBm";
    imagearray[2] = "h%$u@2Nfu8FL9H+R";
    imagearray[3] = "X&NB5tYdUs5u@G#z";
    imagearray[4] = "k#Rc3LGsCdu4q%qZ";
    imagearray[5] = "!$p!Ss5BA%#4zeAa";
    imagearray[6] = "qz63!tue3WCUxJ@R";

    var d = new Date(); /*** create a date object for use ***/
    var i = d.getDay();
  function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("text1").value == "student21" &&
      document.getElementById("text2").value == imagearray[i]) {
      console.log("RIGHT")
    } else {
      console.log("WRONG")
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Mainly, it keeps saying that "validate" is not defined...

`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#41:132'>41:132</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined"`

OR

`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#65:49'>65:49</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: imagearray is not defined"`

Comment: Horrible idea. Those passwords can be seen by anyone with a Browser. You'll want to keep that kind of information in a secure folder and use the Server to query it.

Comment: @StackSlave My website is rarely visited, and if so it is anti inspect element or view source etc.

Comment: Bad practice anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function **validate()** has a scope within the function **chgDailyImg()**. Move it outside of the function fixes the problem.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="text1" /><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="text2" /><br>
  <input type="button" class="button4" style="background-color:#9c9c9c" value="Login" onclick="javascript:validate()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    chgDailyImg();
  }
  
  const imagearray = new Array();
        imagearray[0] = "9G7DcwnWafg*EtMH";
        imagearray[1] = "MDe^5qHTG#P9dHBm";
        imagearray[2] = "h%$u@2Nfu8FL9H+R";
        imagearray[3] = "X&NB5tYdUs5u@G#z";
        imagearray[4] = "k#Rc3LGsCdu4q%qZ";
        imagearray[5] = "!$p!Ss5BA%#4zeAa";
        imagearray[6] = "qz63!tue3WCUxJ@R";
  let i = 0;
  
  function chgDailyImg() {
    let d = new Date(); /*** create a date object for use ***/
    i = d.getDay();
  }

  function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById("text1").value == "student21" &&
      document.getElementById("text2").value == imagearray[i]) {
      console.log("RIGHT")
    } else {
      console.log("WRONG")
    }
  }
</script>
```

Update:
There are some problems with **Scope** of your variables and functions. Hope this reading will give you get a better idea.

[Scope - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: I am still getting errors from this...
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: imagearray is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 36,
  "colno": 49
}

Comment: ``"<a class='gotoLine' href='#62:49'>62:49</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: imagearray is not defined"
``

Comment: I am very new to javascript and this is very confusing can you try your best to explain more, i did read the article, but it's just too much to find all the errors!

Comment: Let's say there are two types of VIP cards that can grant you discount.
One is for the entire mall, you can apply it in any store on any item.
The other one is for Apple only.

Create a variable with in a function is like you applied an Apple only VIP card, you can only use (Access) it with in the Apple store. No otherstores in the mall will accept it. But if you applied a Mall (Gloabl) vip card, you can use the card in any store including Apple.

What you did in your original script was creating everything inside the "Apple store", and try to use them outside of it.

Comment: This reading explains way better than me with scripts. https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript